# Ionic binding model data with ng repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a code that looks like this (in Ionic 1.2):

template.html

```
<form ng-submit="addToCart(products)">
    <div ng-repeat="product in databaseProducts.products.details">
        <input ng-model="products.value" type="number">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">add to cart</button>
</form>
```

and when I try to console.log(products) in my addToCart() function in appropriate controller all I see is "undefined". The value of the product input should correspond to it's id so I can track how many product clients want to order. I also tried to use dynamic model names but since this simple example doesn't work - I don't see the point to paste it here.

Do you know what may cause this and can you point any workaround for this?

Comment: How is products variable declared in your controller?

Comment: I just finished rewriting the controller code and it works :D - am 99% sure that was a typo in products declaration. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Your use of `product` and `products` isn't intuitive - I think it is likely you are somehow confusing the two

Answer (score 0):

You should use `product.value` instead of `products.value`